# Handle Uppercase and Lowercase in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a multiline edit text and  when the user starts typing something in it,i want it to show the text in capital letters and when the user press "ENTER KEY" the letters then he type must be in small letters ( Lower case ).

How can i do this?
right now i am using

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

But it does not allow me to go to next line on pressing enter. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using text watcher

```
scene.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    String s=arg0.toString();

    if(!s.equals(s.toLowerCase())) {
         s=s.toUpperCase();
         scene.setText(s);
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextView);
        edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                  // Perform action on key press
                    edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If this was what you were looking for please do not forget to mark the answer as correct to close the thread.

Comment: 1- On pressing ENTER, it does not go to the next line,

Comment: 2- It does not change the text to Lowercase while i am writing the text, it changes it to lower case after i press the enter key

Comment: Use the code I've written as a starting point, now it's your job suit your needs.